# Pi iteration, display the amount of iterations of pi by the users input

Tags: java, pi

The assignment is 
The following method can be used to approximate the value of Pi:
     Pi/4 = 1 – (1/3) + (1/5) – (1/7) + (1/9) – (1/11) + …

> Write a program that allows the user to specify the number of iterations used in this approximation and display the approximated value of Pi.  Test the program for small, medium and large number of iterations.

It compiles but it not giving me the answers I want. For instance when I put in 1, it gives me 1/3 instead of 8/3. When I pretty much any other number, it just bugs out and I can't get any output.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LabFiveUnitFour {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double n, pi=1, count=1, amount;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("How many pi iterations do you want?");
      amount = input.nextDouble();
      n = amount;

      do {
          pi = ((Math.pow(-1, n)) / (2 * n + 1));
      } while (!(count == amount));

      {
          n = n - 1;
          pi = pi + ((Math.pow(-1, n)) / (2 * n + 1));
          count++;
      }

      pi = 4 * (1 - pi);
      System.out.println(pi + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a weird mashup of a do-while loop and a while loop there.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Typically a loop which executes a fixed number of times is handled by a `for` loop.

Comment: why are you defining count/amount as doubles? you're just using them as integers. allowing for `2.3` iterations makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Why are you reading the number of iterations as a double instead of an integer? If the user inputs "0.4", how will you iterate 0.4 terms?

Comment: You should not use Math.pow(-1,n) to determine whether to add or subrtract the next term, especially with n as a double.

Answer (score 1):

You have a do/while loop that is controlled by comparing count and amount and the body of that loop is not doing anything to modify either of those variables.  The result will be that the loop will never exit.